# rsyslog not logging to auth.log

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, rsyslog

I'm running Ubuntu server 10.04, and my `auth.log` is no longer getting updated. And actually my `auth.log` is empty and everything was being logged to `auth.log.1`, same with syslog, mail, and other logs.

Is that normal for everything to be logged in `*.log.1`? logrotate had been rotating weekly up until now.

And secondly, any idea why this might be happening? All other logs are fine, and I have the default configs for rsyslog.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like logrotate successfully moved /var/log/auth.log to /var/log/auth.log.1 , but did not successfully reload the rsyslog daemon. Therefore, the rsyslog thinks it is still writing to /var/log/auth.log .

If you reload the rsyslog daemon, does it work for you?

A quick manual fix for this is be to restart the rsyslog daemon. rsyslog will then write to the places which are defined in [r]syslog.conf

```
$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: i've tried restarting rsyslog but still no luck. i have a cron job running pretty often, it gets logged to syslog just fine and used to log to auth.log, but for some reason it stopped yesterday.

Comment: Well, *something* is still holding the old auth.log open.  Use `lsof` to see what it is, and make sure it gets restarted in logrotate.